# File handling not working with fstream after reaching eof?

Tags: c++, c++11

On your suggestion i have changed the code as you suggested but still problems are there when ios::out is replaced with ios::ate nothing is written in the file(Writing does not work). Is there any way to check that if the next bit is eof rather than reading it and then checking it? as suggested by you.And sometimes when i do file handling it shows the position of file pointer to be -1 what could that mean???

Code:

```
int main ()

{

    char p[80];
    fstream file("text1.txt",ios::out|ios::in); //if ios::ate is added here it results into infinite loop
    cout<<"Starting position of the file is "<<file.tellg()<<endl;
    getch();
    if(file.is_open())
        cout<<"file is open\n";
    else
        cout<<"file is not open\n";
    getch();
    file.seekp(0);
    while(file>>p)
    {
        cout<<p<<endl;
    }
    file.clear();
    cout<<"\nThe current position of the file pointer is "<<file.tellg()<<endl;
    file.seekp(0);
    if(file.eof())
        cout<<"\n the eof\n";
    while(file>>p)
    {
        cout<<p<<endl;
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Starting position of the file is 0
file is open
Hello
man
how
are
you

The current position of the file pointer is 21
Hello
man
how
are
you
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of reading from file reaching end-of-file causes setting both eof and failbit. Failbit is setted because creating your read loop with `file.eof()` condition doesn't indicate that next read will be the end of the stream. It just states that we didn't reach eof yet, so with:

```
while(file.eof())
{
file >> p;
}
```

It's possible that last read will be eof only, and we'll work with uninitialised data. IF this happens no characters will be extracted inside p and both eof and fail flags will be set.

When working with c++98 need to reset failbit to false by using:

```
file.clear();
```

To avoid bad readings situation you should extract characters from file inside while condition: `while(file >> p)`. I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) questions on stack overflow.

So proper C++98 code should look like this:

```
while(file >> p)
{
  std::count << p << std::endl;
}
file.clear();
file.seekp(0);
while(file >> p)
{
  std::count << p << std::endl;
}
file.close();
```

I tested it couple of times on Visual Studio 2013 and it worked everytime.

Considering `ios::ate` mode:
`ios::out`, `ios::in` are modifiers that states how do we open file in question. If you want to read something from file you need to use `ios::out` flag, and for writing you need to use `ios::in`.

On the other hand `ios::ate` just tells compiler to open file and immediately go to the end of file. So if you substitute `ios::out` with `ios::ate` writing would be impossible, and program will rise failflag on `file << "Hello...";`. 
And if you just want to append data, but read from the beginning of file you should use `ios::app` instead, because it tells to seek eof before each write.

Comment: I have tried this too in the code blocks with gcc compiler this does not work  everytime and if i am using ios::ate this whole does not works.And why do i need to clear the stream everytime after reaching the eof??

Comment: @Harshul I rewroted my answer, previous was awfoul and didn't even scratch the surface of problem imo. Hope it'll help this time :)

Comment: Konrad 'Zegis' your answer was helpful for me but still left me with problems hope you will help me out with them too

Comment: @Harshul `tellg()` returns -1 when failbit is set. And considering question about peeking next bit see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283632/how-to-know-if-the-next-character-is-eof-in-c)